# Fetch and combine two attributes that belong to a specific entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have an `User` entity. It has many attributes like `firstName` and `lastName`. I have to fetch user's full name (`firstName` + `lastName`). I need it as a single `NSString`.

Is it possible?

Comment: concatenate the two strings

Comment: i need complete array of user's full name from core data.

Comment: As always, **post some code**. Let us know the context of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way to do it, IMHO, is the following.

Create a `User` class, subclass of `NSManagedObject`.

Create `fullName` attribute (of type `NSString`) in your entity as **transient** (it will not be stored on disk).

Then override `awakeFromFetch` method to set the `fullName` as a concatenation of `firstName` and `lastName` like the following:

```
self.fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
                            self.firstName, self.lastName];
```

Here the link to the [Core Data doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdManagedObjects.html). In particular, take a look at *Object Life-Cycle—Initialization and Deallocation*.

Hope that helps.